# Unable to display the exact date with angular datepipe

Tags: angular

I am using angular 7. When I am using the date pipe it is printing the next date please see the below code:

```
<div style="text-align: left;width: 80px;white-space:nowrap"> 
  <strong> : {{project.projects_StartDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</strong>
</div>
```

Sample value of the `projects_StartDate` is `2019-03-11T18:30:00.000Z` (*this value is returning from the API*)

- Expected behavior: it should display `03/11/2019`
- Current behavior: it is displaying `03/12/2019`

Please let me know if anyone knows the answer.

Comment: Hi Santhosh yesterday you  had asked a similar question on Javascript - the reason is the same - you need to understand that if time returned by the API is UTC then local time is automatically derived based on time zone settings of the system. Just ensure that the API is returning the time properly in UTC format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date/time is being converted from UTC to local time and that might be on a different day depending on the offset, the current local datetime, and the utc datetime being displayed. If you want to display the UTC date then set the `timezone` in the pipe.

```
{{project.projects_StartDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy" : "UTC"}}
```

See also the [Date Pipe documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) and [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numnxu).